# How to debug a (PCRE) regex passed to grep?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, pcre

I'm trying to debug a regex passed to `grep` that doesn't seem to be working just on my system.

This is the full command that should return the latest terraform release version:

```
wget -qO - "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/latest" | grep -Po '"tag_name": "v\K.*?(?=")'
```

Which seems to be working for others but not me.
Adding a `*` quantifier after `"tag_name":` to match extra spaces makes it work for me:

```
wget -qO - "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/latest" | grep -Po '"tag_name": *"v\K.*?(?=")'
```

Here's the response from the `wget` without piping to `grep`:

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/20814583",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/20814583/assets",
  "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/20814583/assets{?name,label}",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v0.12.12",
  "id": 20814583,
  "node_id": "MDc6UmVsZWFzZTIwODE0NTgz",
  "tag_name": "v0.12.12",
  "target_commitish": "master",
  "name": "",
  "draft": false,
  "author": {
    "login": "apparentlymart",
    "id": 20180,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIwMTgw",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/20180?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/apparentlymart",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/apparentlymart/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "prerelease": false,
  "created_at": "2019-10-18T18:39:16Z",
  "published_at": "2019-10-18T18:45:33Z",
  "assets": [],
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/tarball/v0.12.12",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/zipball/v0.12.12",
  "body": "BUG FIXES:\r\n\r\n* backend/remote: Don't do local validation of whether variables are set prior to submitting, because only the remote system knows the full set of configured stored variables and environment variables that might contribute. This avoids erroneous error messages about unset required variables for remote runs when those variables will be set by stored variables in the remote workspace. ([#23122](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23122))"
}
```

And using https://regex101.com I can see that `"tag_name": "v\K.*?(?=")` and `"tag_name": *"v\K.*?(?=")` both match the version number correctly.

So there must be something wrong with my system and I'm just very curious why the original one doesn't work for me and how (if possible) to debug in situations like this.

Comment: Use jq to parse JSON, grep can't understand JSON syntax

Comment: what is the exact version of your grep?

Comment: @jhnc my grep version is `grep (GNU grep) 3.1`.

Comment: @oguzismail I don't need to parse a json, I'm just trying to get a matching line that contains the version number and remove the excess part. jq is a bit heavy for this sort of thing in my opinion and it's not available on every system, whereas grep will most likely be present on most modern linux distros. Anyways, the regex passed to grep works for other but doesn't work for me so that's what I'm trying to figure out here.

Comment: I get `0.12.12` when I try running your given commands (Also using gnu grep 3.1). (Though I'd use a re like `"tag_name": "v\K[^"]*` instead; no lookahead needed). I don't have a clue why it wouldn't be working for you when it does for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to narrow it down to the following. If I execute the `wget` command without the piped grep and without formatting the json response:

```
wget -qO - "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/latest"
```

then I get a json without any whitespaces (I'll post only one a part of the response):

```
"html_url":"https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v0.12.12","id":20814583,"node_id":"MDc6UmVsZWFzZTIwODE0NTgz","tag_name":"v0.12.12","target_commitish":"master","name":"","draft":false
```

So naturally the original regex `"tag_name": "v\K.*?(?=")` fails because there is no space after `:`

This is clearly not related to the regex that is passed to the grep or the grep itself. I don't see the point in digging into the response itself here so the original question can be considered resolved (Though if someone knows what could be causing this please post a comment.)

Comment: A good argument for using `jq` instead... it doesn't care about how the json is formatted (Though I get it pretty printed when I tried, not compact like that).

Comment: `wget ... | jq -r '.tag_name | ltrimstr("v")'` prints `0.12.12`.

Comment: I agree and use `jq` myself when working with json. But it's not always an option for others. And if you're dealing with some third-party stuff they might not be that open into modifying things and including dependencies like `jq` when "something doesn't work only on my machine"

Answer (score -1):

It is very likely that your RegExp engine does not understand \K. There are many dialects for regexps.

Using standard PCRE regexp terms usually yields good results across all engines.

```
$ curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/latest" | egrep -oe '"tag_name": "v(.*)"'
"tag_name": "v0.12.12"
```

Now if you only want the version number, you need to fetch for the numbers afterwards (as using ?! to ignore a pattern might not always work).

```
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/latest" | egrep -oe '"tag_name": "v(.*)"' | egrep -oe '([0-9]+\.?)+'
0.12.12
```

Comment: I don't think that's the case. It seems like I'm loosing a space between `"tag_name":` and `"v0.12.12"`.
Because adding `*` qualifier in the regex after the space works: `"tag_name": *"v\K.*?(?=")` for me just fine. As well as removing the space between them without the `*` qualifier, like so: `"tag_name":"v\K.*?(?=")`

Comment: Here on OpenBSD your regexp didn't work. Mine did. ;) Tested it on CentOS and FreeBSD as well, works there too :P

Comment: You'd have to be using a really old version of pcre to not have it support `\K`.

Comment: OpenBSD grep doesn't support pcre at all. No wonder it wasn't working when you tried it (plus even if it did you're not using `-P` to use that dialect, you're using `egrep` which uses posix extended regular expressions).

Comment: i'm unsure why we are debating this? it's a universally working solution to the problem posted.